# Fiddler Error 504 - While loading CSS file over external IP

Tags: css, iis-7, fiddler

Our styles and Javascript files are deployed to a central location (CDN). My host file looks like this:

internalIP boxname

externalIP a-record of the website

Now when I try to access a css file(160 kb) using the box name it works fine.  However when I try to access the same css file using the a-record of the website, I get an Error 101 (err_connection_reset) in Chrome.  The same request in Fiddler gives me a 504.  Not sure whats going on.  However files that are 20-30kb in size seem to work fine over both the internal and external IP.

IIS log file shows a status code of 200, even when it fails.

Please let me know if my question makes sense. If not I can explain better.

Comment: What exactly is the text of Fiddler's HTTP/504 error message? Are you really sure that you're seeing a 200 from the failing request? (That seems highly-unlikely)

Comment: [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.  I do see a 200 from the IIS Log.  Also one more thing - our server guys found out that there was an SSL redirect that was happening. once you turn that off - I can see the css file over HTTP - but NOT over HTTPS.